# How to make suffix icon appear at the start of the text area? [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This is my code:

```
TextField(
    key: controller.encryptedTextKey,
    readOnly: true,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
    maxLines: null,
    controller: controller.encryptedTextController,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'text_cryption_encrypted_message_hint'.tr,
    hintMaxLines: 2,
    suffixIcon: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        IconButton(
           onPressed: controller.onSaveEncryptedToClipboard,
           icon: Icon(Icons.copy),
        ),
        IconButton(
            onPressed: controller.onPasteEncryptedFromClipboard,
            icon: Icon(Icons.paste),
         ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

What I have is this:

[image]

What I want is this:

[image]

How can I make this happen? The problem is that the Row's height is not the same as the TextField's height. The Row's height only covers the icons. But when I try height: double.infinity or Expanded(), I get errors. Maybe it's because the icons are kind of "floating" behind the TextField.

Answer (score 0):

Use `suffix:` instead of `suffixIcon` for Row.

```dart
suffix: Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
```

While the suffix  is not always visible, you can use this.

```dart
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    const Expanded(
      child: TextField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
        maxLines: null,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'text_cryption_encrypted_message_hint',
          hintMaxLines: 2,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: Icon(Icons.copy),
        ),
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: Icon(Icons.paste),
        ),
      ],
    )
  ],
),
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It kind of works, but the problem is that the suffix isn't permanently visible. If you don't focus it and don't input any text, it disappears.

Comment: In that case you use Row with TextFiled

Answer (score 0):

Try with a below code snippet that has prefix and suffixicon in a textformField

Don't forget to make necessary changes as per requirement.

Create a Textfield widget like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:row_nation/Utils/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:row_nation/Utils/app_font_size.dart';
import 'package:row_nation/Utils/app_font_weight.dart';

class PassWordTextFormFieldWidget extends StatelessWidget {
final TextEditingController controllerName;
final String hintTxt;
final TextInputType keyboardType;
final Color cursorColor;
final Function(String) onChange;
final Function(String) onSaved;
final String? Function(String?)? validatorData;
final IconData prefixIcon;
final IconData suffixIcon;
final Function() sufficIconTap;
PassWordTextFormFieldWidget({
super.key,
required this.controllerName,
required this.hintTxt,
required this.prefixIcon,
required this.keyboardType,
required this.cursorColor,
required this.onChange,
required this.onSaved,
required this.validatorData,
required this.suffixIcon,
required this.sufficIconTap,
});
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
double? height, width;
height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
return Container(
height: 50,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
color: AppColors.kEmptyDotColor.withOpacity(0.4),
),
child: TextFormField(
controller: controllerName,
cursorColor: cursorColor,
obscureText: true,
textAlign: TextAlign.left,
keyboardType: keyboardType,
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption?.copyWith(
      color: AppColors.kWhiteColor,
      letterSpacing: 0.2,
      fontSize: AppFontSize.fourteenFontSize,
      fontWeight: AppFontWeight.sixHundredFont,
    ),
validator: (value) {
  // widget.validatorData!(value);

  return validatorData!(value);
},
onChanged: (va) {
  onChange(va);
},
onSaved: (val) {
  print(val);
},
decoration: InputDecoration(
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    horizontal: 15,
    vertical: 15,
  ),
  isDense: true,
  hintText: hintTxt,
  hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption?.copyWith(
        color: AppColors.kIconColor,
        fontSize: AppFontSize.twelveFontSize,
        fontWeight: AppFontWeight.fourHundredFont,
      ),
  // When user gets Error

  errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
    borderSide: BorderSide(
      color: AppColors.kRedColor,
    ),
  ),

  //  When user getting error and focuses on a textformfield
  focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
    borderSide: BorderSide(
      color: AppColors.kRedColor,
    ),
  ),
  //  When user Focuses on textformField widget
  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
    borderSide: BorderSide(
      color: AppColors.kSplashBackColor,
    ),
  ),

  //   Default TextformField Color
  enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,

  suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      sufficIconTap();
    },
    child: Icon(
      suffixIcon,
      size: 15,
      color: AppColors.kIconColor,
    ),
  ),

  prefixIcon: Icon(
    prefixIcon,
    size: 15,
    color: AppColors.kIconColor,
  ),

  // border: InputBorder.none,
),
),
);
}
}
```

and use it like a below

```
          PassWordTextFormFieldWidget(
          controllerName: passwordController,
          prefixIcon: Icons.lock,
          suffixIcon: Icons.visibility_off,
          sufficIconTap: () {
            print("Visibility Icon Tapped");
          },
          hintTxt: AppStrings.passwordTxt,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          cursorColor: AppColors.kSplashBackColor,
          onChange: (p0) {},
          onSaved: (p0) {},
          validatorData: (p0) {},
          ),
```